# s3 multipart upload always fails on the second part with timeout

Tags: java, amazon-s3, kotlin

I'm trying to get a simple proof of concept multi part upload working in Kotlin using the amazon s3 client based on [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html). The first part uploads successful and I get a response with an etag. The second part doesn't upload a single thing and times out.  It always fails after the first part. Is there some connection cleanup that I need to do manually somehow?

Credentials and rights are all fine. The magic numbers below are just to get to the minimum part size of 5MB.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
fun main() {
    val amazonS3 =
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider())
            .build()


    val bucket = "io.inbot.sandbox"
    val key = "test.txt"
    val multipartUpload =
        amazonS3.initiateMultipartUpload(InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key))

    var pn=1
    var off=0L
    val etags = mutableListOf<PartETag>()

    for( i in 0.rangeTo(5)) {

        val buf = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val writer = buf.writer().buffered()
        for(l in 0.rangeTo(100000)) {
            writer.write("part $i - Hello world for the $l'th time this part.\n")
        }
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()

        val bytes = buf.toByteArray()


        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        md.update(bytes)
        val md5 = Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest())
        println("going to write ${bytes.size}")
        bytes.inputStream()
        var partRequest = UploadPartRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withKey(key)
            .withUploadId(multipartUpload.uploadId)
            .withFileOffset(off)
            .withPartSize(bytes.size.toLong())
            .withPartNumber(pn++)
            .withMD5Digest(md5)
            .withInputStream(bytes.inputStream())
            .withGeneralProgressListener<UploadPartRequest> { it ->
                println(it.bytesTransferred)
            }
        if(i == 5) {
            partRequest = partRequest.withLastPart(true)
        }

        off+=bytes.size

        val partResponse = amazonS3.uploadPart(partRequest)

        etags.add(partResponse.partETag)
        println("part ${partResponse.partNumber} ${partResponse.eTag} ${bytes.size}")

    }
    val completeMultipartUpload =
        amazonS3.completeMultipartUpload(CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key, multipartUpload.uploadId, etags))


}
```

This always fails on the second part with

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestTimeout; Request ID: F419872A24BB5526; S3 Extended Request ID: 48XWljQNuOH6LJG9Z85NJOGVy4iv/ru44Ai8hxEP+P+nqHECXZwWNwBoMyjiQfxKpr6icGFjxYc=), S3 Extended Request ID: 48XWljQNuOH6LJG9Z85NJOGVy4iv/ru44Ai8hxEP+P+nqHECXZwWNwBoMyjiQfxKpr6icGFjxYc=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
```

Just to preempt some of the answers I'm not looking for, my intention with this is NOT to upload files but to eventually be able to stream arbitrary length streams to s3 by simply uploading parts until done and then combining them. So, I can't really use the TransferManager because that requires me to know the size in advance, which I won't. Also, buffering this as a file is not something I want to do since this will run in a dockerized server application. So I really want to upload an arbitrary number of parts. I'm happy to do it sequentially; though I wouldn't mind parallelism.

I've also used "com.github.alexmojaki:s3-stream-upload:1.0.1" but that seems to keep a lot of state in memory (I've ran out a couple of times), so I'd like to replace it with something simpler.

**Update.** Thanks ilya in the comments below. Removing the `withFileOffset` fixes things.

Comment: My wild guess is that call of `withFileOffset` might mess the thing up, could you comment out the call? I believe `withFileOffset` should be used only in conjunction with `withFile`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Removing `withFileOffset` fixes things. Thanks @Ilya for pointing this out.

Here's a simple outputstream that I implemented that actually works.

```
package io.inbot.aws

import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadResult
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest
import mu.KotlinLogging
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.Base64

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {  }
class S3Writer(
    private val amazonS3: AmazonS3,
    private val bucket: String,
    private val key: String,
    private val threshold: Int = 5*1024*1024
) : OutputStream(), AutoCloseable {

    private val etags: MutableList<PartETag> = mutableListOf()

    private val multipartUpload: InitiateMultipartUploadResult = this.amazonS3.initiateMultipartUpload(InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key))

    private val currentPart = ByteArrayOutputStream(threshold)

    private var partNumber = 1

    override fun write(b: Int) {
        currentPart.write(b)
        if(currentPart.size() > threshold) {
            sendPart()
        }
    }

    private fun sendPart(last: Boolean = false) {
        logger.info { "sending part $partNumber" }
        currentPart.flush()

        val bytes = currentPart.toByteArray()

        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        md.update(bytes)
        val md5 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(md.digest())
        var partRequest = UploadPartRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withKey(key)
            .withUploadId(multipartUpload.uploadId)
            .withPartSize(currentPart.size().toLong())
            .withPartNumber(partNumber++)
            .withMD5Digest(md5.contentToString())
            .withInputStream(bytes.inputStream())

        if(last) {
            logger.info { "final part" }
            partRequest = partRequest.withLastPart(true)
        }

        val partResponse = amazonS3.uploadPart(partRequest)

        etags.add(partResponse.partETag)

        currentPart.reset()

    }


    override fun close() {
        if(currentPart.size() > 0) {
            sendPart(true)
        }
        logger.info { "completing" }
        amazonS3.completeMultipartUpload(CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key, multipartUpload.uploadId, etags))
    }

}


fun main() {
    val amazonS3 =
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider())
            .build()

    val bucket = "io.inbot.sandbox"
    val key = "test.txt"

    try {
        S3Writer(amazonS3, bucket, key).use {
            val w = it.bufferedWriter()
            for (i in 0.rangeTo(1000000)) {
                w.write("Line $i: hello again ...\n")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        logger.error(e.message,e)
    }
}
```